# How to make the Next and Previous Button code for the below ArrayList?

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, android-widget, arraylist

I have made the ArrayList and addind the value one by one in it by the coading. I can able to see that whole arrayList as like below code:

```
//  TO DISPLAY DATA
                for(int j=0;j<tempEmployerList.size();j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("================ Employee: "+(j+1)+"======================");
                    m = new Employer();
                    m=tempEmployerList.get(j);
                    //System.out.println("TaxCodeHeading: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getOrderName());
                    System.out.println("TaxCode: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getTaxcode());
                    System.out.println("PayPeriod: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getPayPeriod());
                    System.out.println("Frequency: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getPayFrequency());
                    System.out.println("Salary/Wage: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getSalaryWage());
                    System.out.println("NetGross Amount: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getNetGrossAmount());
                    System.out.println("KiwiSaverMember: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getKiwiSaverMember());
                    System.out.println("Employee Deduction: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getEmployeeDeduction());
                    System.out.println("Complying Fund Member: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getComplyingFundMember());
                    System.out.println("Fund Contribution: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getFundContribution());
                    System.out.println("ESCT Tax Rate: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getESCTTaxRate());
                    System.out.println("Child Support Deduction: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getChildSupportDeduction());
                    System.out.println("Payroll giving Donation: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getPayrollDonation());
                }

TOTAL_EMPLOYEE=tempEmployerList.size();
empIndex = TOTAL_EMPLOYEE;
```

Now i want to view that every element of that array list on the one by one based on the next and previous button click.

So can anyone help me for that ?

I have try it like below code:

**For nextButton click:**

```
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Index is:"+empIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 System.out.println("The Employer Size is: "+tempEmployerList.size());
                 if((empIndex)==TOTAL_EMPLOYEE){
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no any Employee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }else{
                     if(empIndex == 0){
                         empIndex = empIndex+1;
                     }
                     empIndex = empIndex+1;
                     if(empIndex==TOTAL_EMPLOYEE){
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no any Employee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }else{
                         System.out.println("the Index IS::::" +empIndex);
                         headerText.setText("Emp "+(empIndex));
                         //empIndex = empIndex + 1;
                         Employer m = new Employer();
                         int j = empIndex-1;
                         m=tempEmployerList.get(j);
                         //System.out.println("TaxCodeHeading: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getOrderName());
                         System.out.println("TaxCode: "+(j)+" = "+m.getTaxcode());
                         System.out.println("PayPeriod: "+(j)+" = "+m.getPayPeriod());
                         System.out.println("Frequency: "+(j)+" = "+m.getPayFrequency());
                         System.out.println("Salary/Wage: "+(j)+" = "+m.getSalaryWage());
                         System.out.println("NetGross Amount: "+(j)+" = "+m.getNetGrossAmount());
                         System.out.println("KiwiSaverMember: "+(j)+" = "+m.getKiwiSaverMember());
                         System.out.println("Employee Deduction: "+(j)+" = "+m.getEmployeeDeduction());
                         System.out.println("Complying Fund Member: "+(j)+" = "+m.getComplyingFundMember());
                         System.out.println("Fund Contribution: "+(j)+" = "+m.getFundContribution());
                         System.out.println("ESCT Tax Rate: "+(j)+" = "+m.getESCTTaxRate());
                         System.out.println("Child Support Deduction: "+(j)+" = "+m.getChildSupportDeduction());
                         System.out.println("Payroll giving Donation: "+(j)+" = "+m.getPayrollDonation()); 
                         }
}
```

**And for Previous Button clicke:**

```
    case R.id.backButton:
                 System.out.println("Total Employee is: "+TOTAL_EMPLOYEE);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Index is:"+empIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 if(empIndex == 0){
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.taxCodeFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.payPeriodFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.salaryWageFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.payFrequencyFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.employeeDeductionFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.employeeContributionFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.childSupportDeductionFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.payrollDonationFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.kiwiSaverMemberFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.complyingFundMemberFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.fundContributionFinalValue=null;
                     PAYEEmployerDetail.ESCTTaxRateFinalValue=null;
                     TOTAL_EMPLOYEE = 0;
                     empIndex = 0;
                     tempEmployerList = null;
                     employerList = null;
                     finish(); 
                 }else{
                     if(empIndex>TOTAL_EMPLOYEE)
                         empIndex = empIndex - (empIndex - TOTAL_EMPLOYEE);
                     empIndex = empIndex -1;
                     System.out.println("the Index IS :" +empIndex);
                     headerText.setText("Emp "+(empIndex+1));
                     Employer m = new Employer();
                     int j=empIndex;
                     m=tempEmployerList.get(j);
                     //System.out.println("TaxCodeHeading: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getOrderName());
                     System.out.println("TaxCode: "+(j)+" = "+m.getTaxcode());
                     System.out.println("PayPeriod: "+(j)+" = "+m.getPayPeriod());
                     System.out.println("Frequency: "+(j)+" = "+m.getPayFrequency());
                     System.out.println("Salary/Wage: "+(j)+" = "+m.getSalaryWage());
                     System.out.println("NetGross Amount: "+(j)+" = "+m.getNetGrossAmount());
                     System.out.println("KiwiSaverMember: "+(j)+" = "+m.getKiwiSaverMember());
                     System.out.println("Employee Deduction: "+(j)+" = "+m.getEmployeeDeduction());
                     System.out.println("Complying Fund Member: "+(j)+" = "+m.getComplyingFundMember());
                     System.out.println("Fund Contribution: "+(j)+" = "+m.getFundContribution());
                     System.out.println("ESCT Tax Rate: "+(j)+" = "+m.getESCTTaxRate());
                     System.out.println("Child Support Deduction: "+(j)+" = "+m.getChildSupportDeduction());
                     System.out.println("Payroll giving Donation: "+(j)+" = "+m.getPayrollDonation());
}
}
```

**Edited**
I also want to Set the same for the delete functionality and for addindg the new data to that ArrayList. How to set the index while i am viewing the data and not at the last position.

So whats wrong in my code ?
Please help me for that.
Thanks.

Comment: what you are getting with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this, you just need to increment the ArrayList position to get the next ArrayList Record and decrement the position to get the previous Record.

```
int position = 0;
```

**Next Button:**

```
  if(position < tempEmployerList.size() - 1){
      position++;
      tempEmployerList.get(position);
      // show the data here
  }
  else
    Log.d("TAG","Reached Last Record");
```

**Previous Button:**

```
 if(position > 0){
       position--;        
       tempEmployerList.get(position);
    // show the data here
  }
  else
    Log.d("TAG","Reach First Record");
```

Comment: And What about data ? Where should i have to show the data ? before increment or after increment ? Please put some code with that data also. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Let me check it. And Thanks for the reply.

Comment: will your please help me for the delete functionality also. as i can able to delete the index but if there are more then one data in to arraylist and if i am continuasly deleting the data then i got the error of indexoutofbound. So please help me for that also.