# Android - Go to next found word from EditText in TextView

Tags: android, search, textview

I have a TextView and I can search some words, so that they're marked.

The TextView is named textView and it shows the text, I have an EditText Etxt to get the searched word and a Button to start the search. The code above is the code of the search. The app marks all found words big and italic. And I have a TextView text_total which shows the number of found words.

The problem: But if there is a searched word in the text below the shown screen, you must scroll and find the marked word:

```
int total = 0;
String word_search = Etxt.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();
String[] array = fullTxt.split("\n");
String word;
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    word = array[i];
    if (word.toLowerCase().contains(word_search)) {
        String abc = word.trim();
        st.append("<b><i>" + abc + "</i></b>");
        total++;
    } else {
        st.append(word);
    }
    st.append("<br>");
}
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + st));
text_total.setText("Ergebnisse: " + total);
```

Now, I have a problem because the text is too long to see all search results. I want that I have a 'back' and a 'next' button and the view goes to the next result if I click the next button and that the the found word goes automatically to the shown screen.

Does anyone know how to code this?

That's very important. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Put all the finded words in a list

> List words= new ArrayList();

Add the words to the list

> words.add(word_search);

Finally in next and previous buttons, you need to check the positions of the words in the list

> words.get(position)

See how in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753446/how-to-make-the-next-and-previous-button-code-for-the-below-arraylist)